# condition Script in package.json

Tags: node.js, package.json, npm-scripts

I have two questions:

1. How I can do this `npm run script --production` instead `npm run script --env=production`
2. How I want to pass as an argument to another script something like, if you want to create database on development you just run `npm run dev --development --create-database` or if you wanna drop development database `npm run dev --development --drop-database`, this is because I want to add one script to handle create or drop database but if you are doing this in production database, it will throw you a warning..

This is what I have until now

```
"dev": "NODE_ENV=development nodemon src/serve.js",
"start": "NODE_ENV=production src/serve.js",
"test": "NODE_ENV=test jest --testTimeout=10000 --runInBand --detectOpenHandles",
"db:create": "NODE_ENV=$npm_config_env npm run db:condition",
"db:drop": "NODE_ENV=$npm_config_env npx sequelize-cli db:drop",
"db:condition": "if [[ ${NODE_ENV} == \"production\" ]]; then npm run warning; else npm run db:reset; fi",
"db:reset": "npx sequelize-cli db:drop && npx sequelize-cli db:create && npx sequelize-cli db:migrate && npx sequelize-cli db:seed:all",
"warning": "echo \"You can't do this on production\""
```

If you can see I only add condition for "db:create".

Comment: Why not create a script for each condition? Instead of `npm run script --production` you do `npm run script:production`

Comment: nonon, that was an example for explain what i want to do with flag, for production or dev i only run "npm run dev" but to mgirate database i need to set the environment and i would like to know how i can do something like npm run db:create --development to set the environment where it gonna migrate the db